# how to write a unicode file (jpg) to another file from url request in python

Tags: python, file-io, unicode, python-requests

I am trying to download a `.jpg` file from a url using `requests` module in python. This is what I tried.
There is no error. but I am unable to open the output file.

```
>>> import requests
>>> l = requests.get("http://www.mosta2bal.com/vb/imgcache/2/9086screen.jpg")
>>> l
<Response [200]>
>>> l.text
u'\ufffd\ufffd\ufffd\ufffd\x00\x10JFIF\x00\x01\x01\x00\x00\x01\x00\x01\x00\x00\ufffd\ufffd\x12EExif\x00\x00MM\x00*\x00\x00\x00\x08\x00\x07\x01\x12\x00\x03\x......long text
>>> l.encoding
>>> import codecs
>>> f = codecs.open('out.jpg', mode="w", encoding="utf-8")
>>> f.write(l.text)
```

Comment: First, what does "unable to open the output file" mean? What did you try? What happened?

Comment: Why are you trying to write it in `utf-8` encoding?

Comment: Second, a JPEG file is not text, it's binary data, so it makes no sense to try to treat it as text. If it works at all, it's only by blind luck.

Comment: @abarnert exactly my point.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're trying to access binary data as if it were text. This means that Requests has to guess an encoding for it (and any guess it makes will be wrong, because it's not text) and decode it… just so you can decode it to `utf-8`. If you're really lucky, maybe Requests will guess UTF-8, and your data will just happen to be data that can be round-tripped as UTF-8, so it might work one time in a thousand, at best.

Just ask requests for [binary response content](http://www.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/#binary-response-content), and save it to a binary file.

While we're at it, you never actually `close` the file. You're just sitting there in the interactive interpreter with an open `file` object that hasn't been `flush`ed yet. So, it's entirely possible that the last buffer worth of data, or even all the data, won't be there yet. That's exactly what the `with` statement is for.

So:

```
l = requests.get("http://www.mosta2bal.com/vb/imgcache/2/9086screen.jpg")
with open('out.jpg', 'wb') as f:
    f.write(l.content)
```

Comment: nicely illustrated. thanks. The reason I wrote in utf-8 mode what when I opened the file (which was read in text mode) in editor, I saw unicodes. so I used codecs to write in utf-8. your suggestion is great

Comment: @user1988876: I don't know what you mean by "I saw unicodes". There may be a handful of text embedded in JPEG files (EXIF or another metadata format), but the main bulk of the data is an image, not text, in any character set.

Comment: I meant this `'\ufffd` throughout the file and so I thought it is in unicode. but I am WRONG

Answer (score 1):

First, as @abarnert mentioned in the comment, an image file consists of binary data, not text. To get the data, use `.content` attribute:

```
data = l.content
with open('image.jpg', 'wb') as image: #Open it in binary mode
    image.write(data)
```

Comment: You don't need to use `raw` for that. And, if you _do_, you need to keep `read`ing until you get back `b''`. Just use `content`.

Comment: If you use `stream=True`, then you _have_ to use `raw`, and then you have to read (and write) in a loop. Which is really overcomplicating things for a typical 80KB JPEG. But for a huge file, it's obviously a good idea.